# How can I get rid of mission timers?

Tags: xcom-2

One of the greatest drawbacks of the game right now are mission timers, which almost always force me to play full aggressive, and makes back line soldiers like sharpshooters all but useless.

Is there any way I can mod out the ini files to remove mission timers? I really enjoyed the slower paced gameplay in XCOM: EU, and would like to replicate that as much as possible for XCOM.

Comment: I'm with you on this one. The forced aspect kills the fun. I understand the game putting pressure on the player.

Comment: Sharpshooters are super useful on these timed missions if you get them in a good vantage point. They can shoot without moving, which frees up everyone else to press forward and find them more targets.

Comment: In my opinion, snipers aren't so crippled by mission timers. As long as the mission doesn't involve extraction to a pre-determined evac point, and as long as there's some kind of high ground, non-gunslinger snipers do pretty well. This is especially true if you give them Wraith armor, which gives them tons of extra mobility so that they can get into position. Even without high ground, they do alright. On larger maps they might have to move to new high ground, but a Wraith suit definitely makes this easier.

Comment: For mission types with a per-determined extraction point, like VIP escort/capture missions, you don't want a sniper nest, because your sniper will be too far away from the evac point. If you're going to use a sniper on these missions, bring a gunslinger, who has strong short-medium range attacks with his pistol, which he can use even after moving around a lot, at the expense of sacrificing much of the long range skillset of the traditional sniper. The gunslinger can still take the occasional clutch long range killshot, he'll just be doing it less often.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several mods that do this or something similar:

- The [Disable Timers](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=616964599) mod on Steam Workshop disables timers altogether.
- The [Timer Tweaks](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=616857663) mod increases the time-limits to make them less stressful.
- The [True Concealment](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=619816174) mod makes timers *only* start counting down once you've been revealed.

  - There is a second version of [True Concealment](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618077830) which reduces the time-limits to compensate for the extra time.

Comment: +1 for True Concealment.  What this mod does to the game mechanics really should be built into the core game.